# Picture generation with paraview

Tags: paraview, openfoam

I am currently using Openfoam to run simulations that have nearly 180 time steps. The completed timesteps range from -180 to -6.

I have to generate pictures using paraview. 
I have to generate picture for every 10th timestep i.e -180,-170,-160 and so on.
Is it possible to do this with paraview?

Comment: Hi Aravind, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show what you've tried so far, and describe to what extent it has worked or failed?

Comment: I tried to run animation in paraview but it is generating pictures for every time step which is a lot of pictures...

Comment: Hi Aravind, and thanks for the update. When you have extra information like this, it's best to edit your question to include the new information - that way, it is easy for any reader to understand everything about your question, without having to also scan through the comments.

Comment: @AravindKrishna, can you just setup OpenFOAM to output data every 10 steps, and only then map animation?

Comment: @Petr i can do what you said, but i need the values of every timestep to analyse the behaviour. Can i do this in simple animation or i need python script to generate pic for every 10th time step#

Comment: @AravindKrishna, I don't know an easy receipt in Paraview (that's why I don't post an answer), another way that I can suggest is to copy needed timestep directories into a separate directory, make a `.foam` file there and open it in Paraview. Or even not copy, but make symlinks.

Comment: @Petr Thank you so much ...Will definitely try that